# Text will not overflow in row

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have text in a row that is overflowing and it will not clip properly. Below is a simple hierarchy of my Widget with notes.

```
ListView
  ListItem1
  ...
  ListItemN
    Padding
      Row // mainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
        Row
          IconWidget
            Container
              Padding
                Image // 64px square
          TitleWidget // overflowing but not clipping
            Text // TextOverflow.fade
        ScoreWidget
          Container // boxDecoration, color & borderRadius
            Padding
              Text
```

I have tried wrapping `TitleWidget` in `Expanded`, `Flexible`, and `OverflowBox` and I keep getting infinite length errors. Here is a photo of the rendered content.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved, the middle most Widget needs to be in an Expanded widget. Also cleaned it up a bit.

```
ListView
  ListItem1
  ...
  ListItemN
    Container //padding
      Row
        IconWidget
          Container // padding
            Image // 64px square
        TitleWidget
          Expanded // added Expanded
            Text // TextOverflow.fade
        ScoreWidget
          Container // boxDecoration, color & borderRadius, padding
            Text
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to change the row `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min`

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the "maxlines" attribute to >1?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this, in case anyone needs it.
You can do it using the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package:

```
 Container(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minWidth: 200.0,
      maxWidth: 200.0,
      minHeight: 50.0,
      maxHeight: 150.0,
    ),
    child: AutoSizeText(
      "Your Text",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Example:
[image: Example:]

You can further constrain the text by setting `maxLines` or specify `presetFontSizes` if you wish to restrict specific font sizes.